# Aggregated headers and columns in Slick Grid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I wanted to implement something like [Sencha Aggregation Grid](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:aggregationgrid) in SlickGrid. I have a very bad workaround for it,

```
 var columns = [
      name:getAggregatedName(),  field: 'save', width:160, formatter: customFormatter}
 ];

function customFormatter(){

    var text = '<div> <span style ="float:left"> Value1 </span> <span style ="float:right"> Value2 </span> </div>';
    return text;                
}
function getAggregatedName(){
    var html ="<div style=\"text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid red;\"> <span> Action </span> </div> <span style =\"float:left\"> Action1</span><span style =\"float:right\"> Action2</span>";
    return html;
}
```

Its not appropriate, Its neither extensible, nor it wil give correct formatting.

For diaplaying it properly, i had to change the height of header row in the `slick.grid.js` file which is again wrong way.

Is there any proper way of doing it? All ideas are welcomed

Thanks

**Edit**

Here is the snapshot of what i want.

[image: Snapshot of what i want]

Comment: Did you take a look at the grouping and aggregation SlickGrid example? http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping

Comment: @ghiscoding I have added more info to this question. Can you elaborate on how the example will help in achieving it. I already looked at all the examples, but could not figure out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah you mean merging cells together... That was implemented with the naming "colspan", meaning column spanning. Here is the [example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-colspan.html)

If that does not give you what you want, you could also use the first row (Top Panel row) to display whatever you wish to display. Take a look at this [example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html), then click on the loupe icon (magnifying glass) on top right, you will see the top panel showing up and customized customize for that page only. If you decide to go with the Top Panel, you can use it as follow (basically took it from the example code)

html code

```
<div id="inlineFilterPanel" style="display:none;background:#dddddd;padding:3px;color:black;">
    Show tasks with title including <input type="text" id="txtSearch2">
    and % at least &nbsp;
    <div style="width:100px;display:inline-block;" id="pcSlider2"></div>
</div>
```

then use it your grid definition

```
var options = {
    editable: true,
    ...
    topPanelHeight: 25,
    showTopPanel: true
};

dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({ inlineFilters: true });
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

// move the filter panel defined in a hidden div into grid top panel
$("#inlineFilterPanel")
    .appendTo(grid.getTopPanel())
    .show();
```

**Edit #2**
Alternatively, I also found this fork in which this person made a really nice colspan and rowspan. This is actually probably better than all the others... 

[GerHobbelt Fork](https://github.com/GerHobbelt/SlickGrid/tree/k0stya-rowspan)

Download the code, then run the example named `example-row-span-many-columns.html` and see the first and second row, which are merged header cells

Comment: There's also a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880178/how-do-i-create-merged-cells-in-slickgrid

Comment: The example mentioned in Edit 2, that was what i wanted. Thanks

Comment: See at this example http://hariharanpalani.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-HeaderGrouping.html

Comment: That's also a nice one, glad I could help :)